# Best way by pass parameter in service layer

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Student info table with column Name, Sex,Class, Course, Grade.. etc
I would like to implement a filter, require search by name, by class,by course,by grade ....

I using mybatis by querying the DB.. the query is very simple. But I have to write multiple query to implement these search function.

```
Select * FROM TB where name =#{name} , 

Select * FROM TB where class =#{class},

Select * FROM TB where course =#{course},

Select * FROM TB where grade =#{grade}
```

....

In service layer,
Multiple functions need to implement.

```
List<Student> getStudentByName(String name);

List<Student> getStudentByCourse(String course);
... bla bla ...
```

Question:

is that any simple way to implement this requirement?

what I expected is :

in @service layer, a function can handle all the pass parameter, 
like:

List search(  someParam );

I come out with an idea is using   in mybatis.

```
SELECT * FROM TB WHERE 1 =1 
<if name!=null>
AND name = #{name}
</if>
```

I'm not sure if this is a good practice for approaching.

Comment: Having 4 different methods, executing 4 different queries, seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can

you can do that . refer the below syntax in xml :

```
SELECT * FROM TB WHERE 1 = 1 
<if name != null and name!= ""'>
   AND name = #{name}
</if>
<if class != null and class!= ""'>
   AND class = #{class}
</if>
<if course != null and course!= ""'>
   AND course = #{course}
</if>
<if grade != null and grade != ""'>
   AND grade = #{grade}
</if>
```

Comment: Thank you. I put all select condition in one query, it's good for this scenario.